# How to get exit status of a background process?

Tags: linux, bash, background-process, exit-status

I am running two `mysql`[sp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) in a bash script. I want to start both of them simultaneously (they are running in remote servers) and put them in background, once completed proceed to next step. I want to get the `exit status` of both(to know in case error happened). With this in mind I have tried below with `sleep` command, but not working.

**Edit**ing as per Jeff Schaller's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341172/98471) : Below are what I have tried.

```
givinv@87-109:~$ sleep5 & PID5=$!; exit5=$?; sleep 4 & PID4=$!; exit4=$?; wait $PID5 $PID4; echo $exit5 $exit4
[1] 29530
[2] 29531
No command 'sleep5' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sleep' from package 'coreutils' (main)
sleep5: command not found
[1]-  Exit 127                sleep5
[2]+  Done                    sleep 4
0 0
givinv@87-109:~$ unset exit5 exit4
givinv@87-109:~$ sleep5 & exit5=$?;PID5=$!; sleep 4 & exit4=$?;PID4=$!; wait $PID5 $PID4; echo $exit5 $exit4
[1] 29535
[2] 29536
No command 'sleep5' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sleep' from package 'coreutils' (main)
sleep5: command not found
[1]-  Exit 127                sleep5
[2]+  Done                    sleep 4
0 0
givinv@87-109:~$
```

I **knowingly put sleep5(error command),** but still getting `0` as `exit status`. When I run above commands, I see a line like `[1]- Exit 127 sleep5`. Is it possible to trap that while running from script?

How to get the `exit status` of two commands that run **simultaneously**?

Answer (score 1):

From [the bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), my italicized emphasis:

> wait
>
> wait [-n] [jobspec or pid …]
>
> Wait until the child process specified by each process ID pid or job specification jobspec exits *and return the exit status of the last command waited for.*

I think you've perhaps misplaced your backgrounding symbol `&`:

> sleep 5 ;exit5=$? & PID5=$!;wait $PID5; echo $?; echo $exit5

Says to sleep for 5 seconds; once that's done, set the (zero) exit code into `exit5` as a background process; set the job ID of that assignment into `PID5`; then wait for that assignment to finish; the assignment finished successfully, so `echo` shows that zero; then the last `echo` shows a blank line, as the background process (subshell) has exited, leaving the `exit5` variable unassigned (empty).

Perhaps this is the situation you were going for?

> sleep 5 & PID5=$!; wait $PID5; exit5=$?; echo $exit5

Put `sleep 5` into the background, saving its PID into `PID5`. Wait for the process to exit, then capture its return code into `exit5`, then echo the saved return code.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. But when I tried to run two `sleep` commands simultaneously, it took the total amount(I tried `sleep 4` and `sleep 5` and I want to run that in a total pf `5 seconds` and NOT in `9 seconds`). `sleep 4 & PID4=$!; wait $PID4;exit4=$?; sleep 5& PID5=$!; wait $PID5;exit5=$?; echo $exit5 ; echo $exit4 `

Comment: Because you're waiting between the two of them. Wait for both at the end.

Comment: well, the time is corrected, but not getting proper `exit status`. I tried both below. `sleep5 & PID5=$!; exit5=$?; sleep 4 & PID4=$!; exit4=$?; wait $PID5 $PID4; echo $exit5 $exit4` and `sleep5 & exit5=$?;PID5=$!; sleep 4 & exit4=$?;PID4=$!; wait $PID5 $PID4; echo $exit5 $exit4`. I knowingly put `sleep5`(error command), but still getting `0` as exit status.  PS: When I run above commands, I see a line like `[1]-  Exit 127                sleep5`. Is it possible to trap that while running from script?